# C++, Mongoose: How to make a POST request?

Tags: c++, mongoose-web-server

I'm working on a project that uses Mongoose, and I need to make a POST request to another server. I don't see an example of how to do this in their examples list, does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT to add more detail:

I'm working within a larger C++ app and need to create a simple server such that a user can query the app for information. Right now, I start the server like this:

```
Status  sampleCmd::startServer()
{
    Status stat = MS::kSuccess;

    struct mg_server *server;

    // Create and configure the server
    server = mg_create_server(NULL, ev_handler);
    mg_set_option(server, "listening_port", "8080");
    stopServer = false;

    printf("Starting on port %s\n", mg_get_option(server, "listening_port"));
    while (!stopServer) //for (;;)
    {
      mg_poll_server(server, 1000);
    }

    // Cleanup, and free server instance    
    mg_destroy_server(&server);

    return stat;
}
```

In my event handler, I parse the provided URI for a particular one and then run some commands with the application's API. I need to send these results back to a server for the user to see. It's this latter step that is unclear to me. It seems odd that a web server library wouldn't have *some* client functionality, don't servers need to talk to other servers?

Comment: Mongoose is an HTTP _server_, it does not have client capabilities. You'll need to either implement the protocol yourself or use one of the many libraries available. You've been told this [before](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1115716/user1115716).

Comment: Well, that was for websockets, but I see your point, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out I was thinking about this wrong. I needed to respond to the POST request I was getting. So using mg_printf_data(...) with the connection object worked for me.